# My UK Tier 2 visa was refused, the visa office states I did not send a letter from UK NARIC, but I did. What should I do?

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa, refusal

I had submitted an application for a Tier 2 visa on August 24th 2018.

On September 12th, I got an email from the UK decision centre, asking me to submit within 10 working days a letter from UK NARIC confirming that my degree was taught in English, and send it as a scanned attachment to SheffieldDocsRequested.India@fco.gov.uk.

On September 18th, I emailed my English Language Assessment (ELA) from NARIC to the indicated email address. But, on October 2nd, I got the same email asking me to submit *A letter from UK NARIC.* Since it was not clearly stated which letter from UK NARIC, I emailed to them my ELA and Statement of Comparability (SoC).

Again, on October 16th, I got same email asking to submit a letter from UK NARIC. I resent both the ELA and SoC immediately and mentioned that I had already send them on September 18th and October 2nd.

In spite of all this, I got a refusal letter on October 25th, with the main reason

> You have not provided any confirmation from UK NARIC that your degree was taught in English and you have not provided any confirmation from UK NARIC that the degree you have is deemed to meet the recognised standard of a Bachelor's or Master's degree or a PhD in the UK. We emailed you on 12/09/2018 and 02/10/2018 to request these documents and received no reply.

The documents not being available at assessment appears to be a technical error. The emailed documents are shown in my sentbox folder. I am planning to apply for an administrative review request for reconsideration of the decision on my application.

Comment: @S Sai Does your ELA prove that your course was taught in English, or does it show the level of English you’ve attained?

Comment: Thankyou all....today I received an email from the Entry clearance manager confirming that  it was a mistake from their part to have send the incorrect email address....my refusal decision has been overturned...  email also stated that I will be issued  Entry clearance immediately...

Comment: Hi @SSai, glad to hear they've overturned their decision. A quick comment - it is unfortunate on your part though, that you may have to answer 'yes' to every future "Have you been refused a visa in the past?" questions (or words to similar effect) and explain it is overturned under an administrative review if you apply for another UK visa in the future, or they might see it as a deception (because bureaucracy, duh). You have done nothing wrong in this application, it is just bad luck that lingers.

Comment: Furthermore, can you please put the comment on what you did and the result as an answer, so it might help other visa applicants in the future?

Comment: Can I reiterate B.Liu's comment.  Please describe how you appealed the decision as an answer to this question.  Self-answered questions are *entirely* acceptable; we are trying to build a database of questions and good answers here - you now have appropriate experience to answer this question.  (The *only* difference about self-answered questions is that you don't get reputation for writing the accepted answer :-) ).