# Can you please give me the email address to send documents from India to Sheffield

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, uk-visitor-visa

I am looking for the correct email address to send documents to Sheffield for a UK visa application. I have been asked to submit my criminal record certificate which I had already scanned at visa center. I am from India. I have sent an email to the provided address but have gotten no acknowledgment.

I was reading [this post](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14993/my-uk-tier-2-visa-was-refused-the-visa-office-states-i-did-not-send-a-letter-fr) where someone mentioned he had the same email address but when he sent documents to that address he got no reply. He was asked again and again and finally his visa was rejected. Then in administrative review, he was told that it was their mistake because email address they provided was wrong. In my case, I have received the same email address. I am worried and stressed after reading that post.

Comment: [This immigration forum](https://www.immigrationboards.com/uk-tier-4-student-visas/additional-information-t237774.html) listed the address SheffieldDocs.RequestedIndia@fco.gsi.gov.uk . I cannot verify its authenticity, but the domain name (that after the @) matches my experience in previous correspondence with home office.

Comment: Thanks dear I got the real one I sent my documents and hot an automated reply  . The one u have mentioned is correct one. How mean they send me a wrong address I have been waiting for so long after sending them previously.

Comment: Mistakes do happen, it just happen to be a very unfortunate and frustrating one. Can you post the right email as the answer, and perhaps also mentioned you have received an automated reply, to give a credible answer for those who may be in the same boat as you are?

Comment: Yes surely how can I add the screen shot. Till the. It's SheffieldDocs.RequestedIndia@fco.gsi.gov.uk

Comment: You can upload the screenshot by clicking the 'Add picture' button, it is a square icon depicting two hills and the sun.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a screen shot of an email:

[image: Obnoxious picture of text]