# UK tier 2 visa - Unfair treatment of applications

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I was recently refused a UK tier 2 (General) category visa because I had forgot to send a english language proof certificate with my application.

I completely understand the reasons for refusal. However I also read the following excerpt from the [Tier 2 Policy Guidance document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/791035/Tier_2_Policy_Guidance_03_2019.pdf).

[image]

**Internet is littered with cases where the entry clearance officer has requested for the missing documents ex: [Missing UK NARIC letter](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14993/my-uk-tier-2-visa-was-refused-the-visa-office-states-i-did-not-send-a-letter-fr).**

I have held UK visas before if anybody was supposed to be requested for documents it would be me.

I just want to know why some cases are treated differently than others. If the ECO has to follow the rules specified in the doucment above then why some applications and applicants are treated differently than others?

Should I apply for an administrative review quoting this?

Screenshot of the refusal letter

[image]

Comment: Based on general usage, ‘may’ indicates possibility. It is not therefore a rule that must be followed. Proof of English is a mandatory document therefore it would seem the ECO did indeed follow the rules.

Comment: I do understand `may` indicates a posibility. But how come he gets to decide the outcome of an application? i.e., wheather to request for the documents or not? This circustance is not even documented anywhere. it's a giant gaping hole in the system.

Comment: @ Griffin Taimer It’s his job to decide based on the application submitted. It would not be fair (or realistic) to expect that ECOs spend time requesting missing documents for every single application - it’s the applicant’s responsibility to pay attention to the requirements. Underneath the section the OP quoted it also says ‘we will not ask for additional documents if your application will be refused for other reasons’. It may help the OP get a better answer if they post a copy of the refusal notice with personal information blanked out.

Comment: @Traveller, once again I completely understand the reasons for refusal. And I agree its the applicants responsibility to pay attention to the requirements. I can confirm that I have been refused solely due to the missing document, which in some "special" cases the ECO has requested the applicant to submit within 10 days. My question is plain and simple as to why some applications are treated differently than others and why isn't this branching in decision not documented?

Comment: "How come he gets to decide...?" "Why some applications are treated differently?" Because they can. Maybe it occurred because the examiner had cornflakes for breakfast, maybe because he *didn't* have cornflakes for breakfast. Maybe it is a "gaping hole in the system," but they're not your rules, they're their rules. The letter does say you were refused because you didn't include the required evidence of a degree taught in English. They can do that because they're not required to ask you to augment your application. Because of that, I think administrative review will not change the decision.

Comment: @David, appreciate your input. I completely agree with you. I have raised this issue with the UKVI complaints requesting for a closure on this (not accusing the ECO ofcourse). I am not going to apply for an administrative review, but I am genuinely concerned that this grey area can lead to a lot of irregularity and bias towards the applicants.

Comment: This site has seen cases in the past where a visa was refused for reason A. Applicant applied again with reason A fixed, but the new application is refused for reason B. They don't need to list all the reasons why a visa will be refused, just one.

Comment: @mkennedy that makes more sense. Let me look into what else might have caused a rejection.