# UK TIer 2 visa refusal reasons

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I had recently made a visa application which was rejected stating that I had not provided a english language certificate from UK NARIC. I have been assigned points in all other categories (Attributes and maintainance).

However the following heighlightened point mentioned on the [UK tier 2 guidance document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/791035/Tier_2_Policy_Guidance_03_2019.pdf) has gotten me worried about my future application.

> If you have submitted specified documents in which:
>   • documents are missing, for example an English language certificate;
>   • parts of a set of documents (for example, a set of bank statements) are missing; or
>   • a document or evidence has been submitted but is in the wrong format, for example, where a letter must be on letterheaded paper; or
>   • a document or evidence does not contain all the specified information;
>   • a Confirmation for Acceptance of Studies (CAS) or Certificate of Sponsorship(CoS) contains minor errors or missed
>   fields;
>
> we may contact you and/or your representative and/or your sponsor, and
>   request the required documents or missing information.
>   **We will not ask for additional documents if your application will be refused for other reasons.**

I was not asked to submit the missing document and this might mean that my application was refused due to other reasons. But there was only one reason on my refusal letter i.e., the before mentioned missing NARIC certificate.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you meet all the eligibility requirements, and score the required points for ‘attributes’ and ‘maintenance’? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/791583/tier-2-v32.0.pdf#page10

Comment: Yes, I have got points for attributes and maintenance, but missed out on the 10 points needed for english language so was refused. My doubt is regarding this specific comment https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/uk-tier-2-visa-unfair-treatment-of-applications?noredirect=1#comment28229_16209

Comment: Can I not just mention both the names on the aliases section on the application?