# Difference in name in degree certificate and passport Uk tier 2

Tags: uk-visa, names

in all of my academic certificates my surname has been abbreviated (only  the initial as been used), where as my passport contains my Name and surname in full.

Ex:

**Academic documents**
`FirstName L`

**Passport**
`FirstName LastName`

Will this cause any issue in my visa application? If so what can I do to prevent a rejection due to this reason?

Comment: IMHO this will cause a problem (although maybe not if you submitted these same documents in your previous application and UKVI did not include the discrepancy as one of the refusal reasons https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/16227/uk-tier-2-visa-refusal-reasons) Can you get your academic documents changed to show your full name to match your passport, or at least get a letter from the educational institution(s) confirming that the certificates relate to you in your full name?

Comment: Getting the names changed on the certificates is a lengthy and very expensive process. And the university does not offer a letter stating that certificate relates to me. I have contacted UKVI asking the same question, hopefully they'll get back with the answers soon.

Comment: *Why* has the name been abbreviated on your academic qualifications?  Is this traditional in your country, or is it just that your `FirstName` is rather longer than normal, and the overall field has been truncated.

Comment: This is very common in south India. But in the passport the initials have to be expanded. This phenomenon is so common but I am yet find another question or content online mentioning it.